# CSS clip-path property :: why does it not validate?

Tags: css, deprecated, validation

I was googling a lot for it and searched on stackoverflow but I couldn't find a solution to the following problem, yet:

Due to the fact, that the old css-property "clip" is deprecated for quite a while now I would like to replace it by the property "clip-path". Unfortunately it doesn't validate though.

So if i put these two examples in the validator, I get the following errors:

```
.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip-path: rect(0,0,0,0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}
```

> => Property clip-path doesn't exist : rect(0,0,0,0)

```
.reset-visuallyhidden {
    clip-path: none;
    position: static;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

> Property clip-path doesn't exist : none

Am I misunderstanding the [official w3 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking/#the-clip-path)?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Looks like this is a recommendation at the moment so hasn't been added as a valid property in the validators rule set.

Comment: Sounds interesting!
I wonder though why flex-layout does validate even it's listed in a draft document too.
But at least flex-layout is at candidate recommendation stage.

Comment: I doubt this is the reason, but the syntax for `clip-path` has changed. It's not `rect()` anymore, it's `inset(distance_from_top, from_right, from_bottom, from_left)`. You can see it in action here (WebKit browsers only) http://codepen.io/thebabydino/full/bLlfa/